# INSERT statement conflict with foreign key

Tags: c#, conflict, sql-insert, userid

I have 2 tables.'Member' and 'ForgotPassword' table. My problem that i am facing is:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ForgotPassword_User". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.Member", column 'userID'. The

**1st Table is the 'Member' Table:**
userID is the primary key and I set it autoincrement.

**2nd Table is the 'ForgotPassword' Table:**
I set userID as not a primary key but foreign key as reference to the 'Member' table and I set it as auto increment.

What I want is the

*userID on Member table to be inserted to the ForgotPassword Table*

when it runs the second sql line.Any of you guys know what is the problem?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections;



namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public class Member3
    {
        string name;
        string email;
        string gender;
        string dateOfBirth;
        string nationality;
        string race;
        string address;
        string postalCode;
        string mobileNo;
        string password;
        string dateRegistered;
        string securityQuestion;
        string securityAnswer;

        public Member3(string name, string email, string gender, string dateOfBirth, string nationality, string race, string address, string postalCode, string mobileNo, string password, string dateRegistered, string securityQuestion, string securityAnswer)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            this.nationality = nationality;
            this.race = race;
            this.address = address;
            this.postalCode = postalCode;
            this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
            this.password = password;
            this.dateRegistered = dateRegistered;
            this.securityQuestion = securityQuestion;
            this.securityAnswer = securityAnswer;
        }

        public string registerMember()
        {
            string status = "";
            string ConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

             string sql = "INSERT INTO Member (userName,Email,Gender,DateOfBirth,Nationality,Race,Address,PostalCode,MobileNumber,Password,DateRegistered) VALUES(@name, @email, @gender, @dateOfBirth, @nationality, @race, @address, @postalCode, @mobileNo, @password, @dateRegistered) SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Member.userID) AS NewUser_ID";

            string sql2 = "INSERT INTO ForgotPassword (userID,SecurityQuestion, SecurityAnswer) VALUES(@NewUser_ID, @securityQuestion, @securityAnswer)";



                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                   
                    SqlCommand cmd;

                    cmd = new SqlCommand((sql), cn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", dateOfBirth);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", nationality);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", race);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postalCode", postalCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", mobileNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateRegistered", dateRegistered);
                    
                   



                    try
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                   
                    {
                       
                         status = ex.Message;
                         throw;
                         
                    }



                        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2,cn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@securityQuestion", securityQuestion);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@securityAnswer", securityAnswer);

                   try
                    {
                        //cn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                            status = ex.Message;
                            throw;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        status = "Member have been registered successfully!";

                    }
                }
                return status;

            }
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.Follow these steps.

1. You need to return the inserted key from Member table as Ident_Current as an output parameter. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212226/t-sql-returning-the-new-insert-identity-to-c-sharp).
2. remove the autoincrement of user id on forgotpassword table.
3. Insert the userid returned as output parameter in step-1 into the ForgotPAssword table

Comment: Do you have any reference or demonstrate me because I am really new to programming

Comment: i have added the example link.

Comment: Did you mean like this?I have edited my sql and sql2 line.I do hope you can help me step by step and im sorry for troubling as im new

Comment: almost, a part from that you need to save the value you have fetched in sql1 to some variable that you can pass in your sql2

Comment: I get the logic and implement it.But i cant get it. Can you demonstrate me?

Answer (score 0):

add SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the end of your query

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Member   (userName,Email,Gender,DateOfBirth,Nationality,Race,Address,PostalCode,MobileNumber,Password,DateRegistered) VALUES(@name, @email, @gender, @dateOfBirth, @nationality, @race, @address, @postalCode, @mobileNo, @password, @dateRegistered) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

and get your new Id using

```
    int NewId= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

after that pass it as parameter to your sql2 query

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @No One, you can achieve entire thing in your sp and call that sp with required parameters thats all. Just an example not actual query.

```
Create proc MyProc
(@Param1 varchar(20), @Param2 varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Id as int  -- in case your PK is auto increment
Insert into Table1(B,C) Vaues(@Param1,@Param2)
Set @Id = @@Identity
Insert into Table2(FK_Table1,D)Values(@Id,@Param2) -- Here Id will be the FK , which you are 
                                         getting from the PK of the main table. 
END
```

Now your both tables are synced and you wont get any such errors.

In your cs embedd two more lines

```
cmd.CommandText = "MyProc";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure // instead of .Text
```